# Pod looses network connection (connection reset errors) during preStop period

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, ingress-nginx

**Environment:**
I am running an Spring boot HTTP server and an HTTP client pod, where the client sends requests to the server using the `myserver.svc.cluster.local` address. Both server and client communicate over a keep-alive session. And the server is configured with a `preStop` hook set to 10 seconds during rolling updates

```
 A(pod)---
          | -- myserver(svc) <--[HTTP request with keep-alive]-- myclient(svc) --- C(pod)
 B(pod)---
```

**Issue:**
When performing a rolling update on the `myserver`, the client experiences a 2 times of a connection reset error.
Each connection reset error occurs immediately as the each server pod enter the Terminating state. (beginning of preStop session)

**Detailed condition:**
Despite the preStop being set to 10 seconds, which should theoretically allow existing keep-alive sessions to continue without accepting new HTTP traffic, the server's IP is immediately removed from the endpoints upon the preStop hook initiation.
As a result, keep-alive sessions, which should have been maintained with Pod A, are transferred to Pod B.

**ex)** For example, the client sends an HTTP GET request with a sequence number `61293`, which was associated with a keep-alive session on Pod A. However, as soon as preStop on Pod A initiates, this packet is redirected to Pod B. Pod B, receiving a packet with an unexpected sequence number, sends an RST packet back to the client, resulting in a connection reset error.

**What I Expected:**
While I expect that new HTTP traffic will not reach the pod during the preStop period, **I also expect that existing keep-alive sessions should be preserved.** However, this is not happening. Is this a bug, or is it intended behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR; Kubernetes `Services` don't support connection draining.

As described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/pod-lifecycle/#pod-termination) and [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/services/pods-and-endpoint-termination-flow/) from the networking perspective pod termination flow looks like that:

1. Terminate pod API call is received
2. Pod is immediately removed from `Endpoints` but it still listed in `EndpointSlices` as:

```
"conditions": {
   "ready": false,
   "serving": true,
   "terminating": true
}
```

As you can see Pod is marked as still serving traffic but it doesn't accept new connections.

3. Kubernetes waits for Pod `preStop` hook completion and then sends `SIGTERM` signal to it. Pod gets removed from `EndpointSlices`.
4. Kubernetes waits until `terminationGracePeriodSeconds` period is over and then sends SIGKILL to Pod (if it doesn't finish up to this moment).

Unfortunately, `EndpointSlices` are not used by Kubernetes `Services`. `EndpointSlices` were created in order to allow external networking implementations to support advanced deployment techniques like truly zero-downtime updates.

You may use Load Balancer implementations that support this functionality such as cloud load balancers (AWS ALB, GKE LB, Azure AppGW). Nginx Ingress doesn't have support for this.

If you're running in GKE you can read more about it here: https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/troubleshooting/load-balancing#500-series-errors

Comment: Does this mean that, in the case of `EndpointSlice`, even if Pod A's IP is removed from the endpoint during rolling update, the packet with `SEQ: 61293` —used in a keep-alive session with Pod A— will still be correctly delivered to Pod A?

Comment: Yes, if the load balancer supports EndpointSlices.